# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput' Python3 and pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to use 'pynput', so I used pip to add it to my environment.
The installation proceeds without problem.
But I am unable to import it into my project.

I am using python 3.8.1 on my environment.
I used pip3 for installation.
I have already tried to install pynput, uninstall it and reinstall it multiple times.
My .py file doesn't have a confusing name like "pynput.py"
I am comfortable with my environment when I try to execute my file.
I am trying to run from my terminal or VSCodium, and neither of them works.
And I work on Debian 10.

pip freeze :

```
pynput==1.6.7
python-xlib==0.26
six==1.14.0
```

Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./play.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pynput import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'
```

So I don't understand why it doesn't work.

thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating my project, I was not working under an environment, so I used the classic shebang: `#!/bin/python3`.

Then, I went under an environment to use pynput, but I just forgot to change my shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

So, actually, I didn't risk finding pynput

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible you have two versions. Rry installing with `python3 -m pip install pynput` or you should use some older version of Python. I am using 3.7.5 and its works perfect for me.

Try importing from the terminal.

[image: pic with interpreter importing pynput]

Comment: I have already tried `python3 -m pip install`, but unfortunately it does not work.
However, importing from the terminal works ...